# Set the output of Azure stream analytics to be Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to use the event hub as the output sink for the Azure stream analytics and the code to do it is shown below.

```
  OutputCreateOrUpdateParameters jobOutputCreateParameters = new OutputCreateOrUpdateParameters()
        {
            Output = new Output()
            {
                Name = streamAnalyticsOutputName,
                Properties = new OutputProperties()
                {
                    Serialization = new JsonSerialization
                    {
                        Properties = new JsonSerializationProperties
                        {
                            Encoding = "UTF8"
                        }
                    },

                    DataSource = new EventHubOutputDataSource
                    {
                        Properties = new EventHubOutputDataSourceProperties

                        {
                            ServiceBusNamespace = "UKFC2-ns",
                            SharedAccessPolicyName = "manage",
                            SharedAccessPolicyKey = "aWFOgfkXPCYz5fdLMIIPXGEkT0EszW+g/OEOI3jhx5U=",
                            EventHubName = "ukfc1",
                            PartitionKey = partition
                        }
                    }
  }
```

What I want to do is to send the result of the stream analytics to a specific partition in the event hub. I did it by setting the PartitionKey property to a string I defined. However, that doesn't work. It seems that the partitionKey property in the EventHubOutputDataSourceProperties is not the partition key used in the event hub. Then my question is how can I send the to a specific partition and set the partition key to what I want.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If that's a real key, you may want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

The PartitionKey property is expecting a column from your query output.  To solve this, add a column in your query that represents the partition you want. If your input doesn't have the EH partition you want, you could hard code it into the query:

```
SELECT '1' AS EHPartition, Column1, ... into output from input
```

Then set the PartitionKey property to "EHPartition".